# docker-compose in Azure Dev Ops pipeline (ADO)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get docker-compose to run in the Azure Dev Ops pipeline with my yaml file but I keep getting errors like the following

```
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

I know that the file exists in the directory structure however as proven from my yaml script output.

```
# task1 - print directories
  - script:
      
      echo '------Current directory is------'

      pwd

      echo '------directories in current directory is------'

      ls
      
      echo '------cd into dir_1------'

      cd dir_1

      echo '------Current directory is------'

      pwd

      echo '------directories in current directory is------'

      ls
  # end task1 

  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: docker compose - Build services
    inputs:
      action: Build services
      azureSubscriptionEndpoint: <redacted>
      azureContainerRegistry: <redacted>
      containerregistrytype: <redacted>
      dockerComposePath: '/agent/_work/6/s/dir_1/docker-compose.yml'
      #dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
      projectName: a_test
      qualifyImageNames: true
      additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
      dockerComposeFileArgs: |
        firstArg=$(firstArg)
        secondArg=$(secondArg)
```

The output of the script is the following

```
------Current directory is------
/agent/_work/6/s
------directories in current directory is------
BuildPushDockerImage.yaml
<redacted>
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.yml.exe
dir_1
------cd into dir_1------
------Current directory is------
/agent/_work/6/s/dir_1
------directories in current directory is------
<redacted>
docker-compose.yaml
```

but I keep getting the unable to locate executable file error. I have tried various other variations as well as listed below but no luck

```
1. 
#dockerComposePath: ./docker-compose.yml
dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Docker Compose was not found. You can provide the path to docker-compose via 'dockerComposePath' 

2. 
dockerComposePath: ./docker-compose.yml
dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: './docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.


3. 
dockerComposePath: docker-compose.yml
dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.


4. 
#dockerComposePath: docker-compose.yml
#dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Docker Compose was not found. You can provide the path to docker-compose via 'dockerComposePath' 


5. 
dockerComposePath: docker-compose.yml
#dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

6. 
dockerComposePath: dir_1/docker-compose.yml
#dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'dir_1/docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.


7. 
dockerComposePath: /agent/_work/6/s/dir_1/docker-compose.yml
#dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: '/agent/_work/6/s/dir_1/docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

8. 
dockerComposePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dir_1/docker-compose.yml'
#dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: '/agent/_work/6/dir_1/docker-compose.yml'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around a bit more I realized that my file permissions were insufficient. After doing a
chmod 777
it worked.